# Fill a model with the data of another model in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, data-binding, model, controller

I have a `.jsp` page which is generated using my `"menuModel"`, Now after visualising this page, the user inserts his/her name and clicks on the `Confirm My Order` button.

[image: Order]

By clicking on this button I want to copy the data of this `menuModel` to another model named "ordersModel". Due to the fact that this `ordersModel` is not instantiated, I don't know how to copy the data of `menuModel` into `ordersModel`.

```
<form:form id="myOrderMenuId" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/OrderSent" method="post" commandName="ordersModel" >
            <c:forEach items="#{menuModel.foodList}" var="foodModel" varStatus="status">
                <c:if test="${foodModel.quantity != 0}">
                <!-- <form:hidden value='${foodModel.foodName}' path='orders[${status.index}].foodName'/>
                <form:hidden value='${foodModel.quantity}' path='orders[${status.index}].quantity'/> -->
                    <div>
                        <table class="itemList">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 170px">
                                    <span id="foodNameId${foodModel.foodId}"><c:out value="${foodModel.foodName}"/></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="quantityId${foodModel.foodId}" style="margin-left: 110px;"><c:out value="${foodModel.quantity}"/></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="priceId${foodModel.foodId}" style="margin-left: 110px;"><c:out value="${foodModel.price}"/></span>
                                    <span> &euro;</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="eachPrice" id="totalPriceId${foodModel.foodId}" style="margin-left: 110px;"><c:out value="${foodModel.totalPrice}"/></span>
                                    <span> &euro;</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>

            <span class="itemList" style="color: #80FF00; margin-left: -300px">Total:</span>
            <span id="totalPayment" class="itemList" style="color: #80FF00; margin-left: 5px"></span>
            <span class="itemList" style="color: #80FF00;"> &euro;</span><br/>
            <div class="itemList" style="margin-left:-1130px">Your Name: <input path="ownerName" name="orderName" class="myInbox" id="orderName"/></div>
            <button id="viewMyOrder" class="greyButton" style="position:relative; left: -530px">Confirm My Order</button>
</form:form>
```

And this is my `OrdersModel`:

```
public class OrdersModel {

  private String ownerName;
  private List<Order> orders;

  //getters and setters
}
```

How is it possible to copy the data into the `ordersModel`, as I commented in the code.

**UPDATE**

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String viewMyOrder(Model model, 
        @ModelAttribute("menuModel")MenuModel menuModel) {
    logger.info("You are in view my order page.");

    List<FoodModel> foodModelList = new ArrayList<FoodModel>();
    for (FoodModel foodModel : menuModel.getFoodList()) {
        FoodModel foodModelNew = new FoodModel(); 
        if (foodModel.getQuantity()!=0){
            foodModelNew.setFoodId(foodModel.getFoodId());
            foodModelNew.setFoodName(foodModel.getFoodName());
            foodModelNew.setQuantity(foodModel.getQuantity());
            foodModelNew.setPrice(foodModel.getPrice());
            foodModelNew.setTotalPrice(foodModel.getQuantity() * foodModel.getPrice());
        }
        foodModelList.add(foodModelNew);
    }
    menuModel.setFoodList(foodModelList);
    return "myOrder";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/OrderSent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String orderSent(@ModelAttribute("ordersModel")OrdersModel ordersModel, 
        @RequestParam("orderName") String owner, Model model) {
    logger.debug("Your order has been received");

    model.addAttribute("owner", owner);


    return "orderSent";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just populate `OrdersModel.orders` with the `FoodModel`s in the controller and then render the JSP?

```
<form:form id="myOrderMenuId" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/OrderSent" method="post" commandName="ordersModel" >
            <c:forEach items="#{ordersModel.order}" var="foodModel" varStatus="status">

...
```

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String viewMyOrder(Model model, @ModelAttribute("menuModel")MenuModel menuModel) {
    logger.info("You are in view my order page.");

    OrdersModel ordersModel = new OrdersModel()

    List<FoodModel> foodModelList = new ArrayList<FoodModel>();
    for (FoodModel foodModel : menuModel.getFoodList()) {
        Order foodModelNew = new Order(); 
        if (foodModel.getQuantity()!=0){
            foodModelNew.setFoodId(foodModel.getFoodId());
            foodModelNew.setFoodName(foodModel.getFoodName());
            foodModelNew.setQuantity(foodModel.getQuantity());
            foodModelNew.setPrice(foodModel.getPrice());
            foodModelNew.setTotalPrice(foodModel.getQuantity() * foodModel.getPrice());
        }
        ordersModel.add(foodModelNew);
    }
    model.addAttribute("ordersModel", ordersModel);
    return "myOrder";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added also my controller in order to be more specific, could you please see what's wrong with my code? /myOrder is the page which I put the screenshot.
I just want to copy the foodName and it's quantity to the ordersModel.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to copy `MenuModel` to `OrderModel.orders`. The best place to do it is `Controller.viewMyOrder`.  That way `orderSent()` will have the full object prepopulated. You could also put `MenuModel` in session and copy it manually in `orderSent()`.

Comment: But could you please explain how is the procedure of putting it in Controller.viewMyOrder??? thanks again

Comment: One last thing, Now I added ordersModel to my model, I want to pass it to the "/OrderSent" controller. How could I do that? because the  model.addAttribute("ordersModel", ordersModel); has been done in the "/myOrder" controller, I want it to be the model for "/OrderSent" controller.

Comment: You should already be able to do that. I mean, In  `viewMyOrder()` `ordersModel` is added to the model, in the jsp the commandName references ordersModel:  `commandName="ordersModel"` and the controller method also has ordersModel as ModelAttribute: `orderSent(@ModelAttribute("ordersModel")OrdersModel ordersModel`